# Flask: how to check existence of the one-to-many backref

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Two Models as follows:

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
```

Be sure the user exists, and hasn't post any comment yet.

then in the template file

```
{% if user.comments %}
    do stuff
{% else %}
    no comments yet
{% endif %}
```

The if-else condition couldn't go to the else branch.

If I use the code as follow:

```
comments = Comment.query.filter_by(author_id=user.id).all()

{% if comments %}
    do stuff
{% else %}
    no comments yet
{% endif %}
```

It could output

```
no comments yet
```

Why not user.comments works?

Comment: Try to print `user.comments` in your python code before pass it to template file.

Answer (score 2):

It's easily explained as when you write `if user.comments` it will always be True, because it's not None, even when empty:

```
>>> user.comments
<sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery object at 0x7fa6e0b456a0>
>>> user.comments.all()
[]
```

You see that even when the query returns nothing, it's type is not None, its a sqlalchemy object:

```
>>> type(user.comments)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery'>
```

Maybe you could use len() or user directly user.comments.all(), or better:

```
{% if user.comments.count() > 0 %} 
do stuff
{% else %}
no comments yet 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: One may prefer to use `user.comments.exists()`. Or even better, eager-loading comments for the view in which one shows users' comments.

Comment: I was thinking about {% if user.comments.count() > 0 %} do stuff
{% else %}  no comments yet {% endif %}

But you have many options here. I editted my response to include the template

Comment: @krassowski `.filter(cls.user.exists())` results in has no attribute 'exists'

Comment: @AlxVallejo, did you use `lazy='dynamic'`?

Comment: @krassowski I dont understand why i would need to alter the backref relationship to support a specific join query...